# robots.txt ignrore all folders but crawl all files in root

Tags: apache, robots.txt

should i then do

User-agent: *

Disallow: /

is it as simple as that?
or will that not crawl the files in the root either?

basically that is what i am after - crawling all the files/pages in the root, but not any of the folders at all
or am i going to have to specify each folder explicitly.. ie

disallow: /admin

disallow: /this

.. etc

thanks

nat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example will block all all the files in root.

There isn't a ["standard"](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) way to easily do what you want without specifying each folder explicitly.

Some crawlers however [do support extensions](https://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) that will allow you to do pattern matching. You could disallow all bots that don't support the pattern matching, but allow those that do.

For example

```
# disallow all robots
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

# let google read html and files
User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /*.html
Allow: /*.pdf
Disallow: /
```

Comment: actually ended up doing it explicitly for each folder..
thanks though - not because it didnt work however